# Filtering a list of strings

Tags: python, string, tuples

The problem has the following parameters:

> Write a function called only_a that takes in a list of strings and returns a list of strings that contain the letter 'a'.

This is code I am trying to use:

```
def only_a(starting_list):
  i = 'a'
  final_list = ()
  
  for char in starting_list:
    if i in starting_list:
      final_list = final_list + starting_list.append[0]
  return final_list

t_string_list = ['I like apples', 'I like tea', 'I don\'t', 'Never']
print(only_a(t_string_list))
```

I keep getting () as a result.

Comment: Does this help?: "[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)".

Comment: `return [value for value in starting_list if 'a' in value]` ... ? There's too much wrong in your original program, starting at `final_list = ()`. You might want to do `print(type(final_list))` to see what you defined there.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. What's your question? It looks like you have a typo where `if i in starting_list` should be `if i in char`, but beyond that, there are other major problems with your code. If you still need debugging help after fixing the typo, you need to make a [mre]. If this is homework, please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should a bit change your solution to have it works:

```py
def only_a(starting_list):
  i = 'a'
  final_list = []
  
  for char in starting_list:
    if i in char:
      final_list.append(char)
  return final_list

t_string_list = ['I like apples', 'I like tea', 'I don\'t', 'Never']
print(only_a(t_string_list))
```

Comment: FWIW, the loop can be easily turned into a comprehension: `final_list = [s for s in starting_list if i in s]`

Comment: Yep, Thanks!
The same suggestion from Matthais in comments under the question

Answer (score -1):

There is a confusion of types here.

`()` is a tuple, `[]` is a list, and

`final_list = final_list + starting_list.append[0]` is treating final_list as a string since you are concatenating(adding) another presumably string. But

`starting_list.append[0]` errors are that append is not an attribute of starting_list and/or that the append list function is not subscriptable(can't be indexed). `anotherlist.append(alist[0])` appends the value in alist at `[0]` to anotherlist.

`[0]` only gets you a value at index 0 of a string or tuple or list

this is why you are getting an empty tuple but I am surprised it gets that far.

`for char in starting_list:` implies that you are thinking of the list as a string instead of a list of strings.

So a suggestion to explore the different types in Python.