# Filtering a list - Typerror

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, filter, list-comprehension

I'm a beginner, I want to filter the list `lista_aziende_raw`. I know for a fact that names that contain `Azienda` are present in the list, but I get an empty list. I guess that `in` only looks for identical results, hence no results.
Is there a way to get what I want using list comprehension, or should I just use the `re` module?

```
lista_aziende_raw = []

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    lista_aziende_raw.append(link.get('href'))

parsing_name = ['Azienda']

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    lista_aziende_raw.append(link.get('href')) 

print(lista_aziende_raw)


lista_aziende_filtered = [x for x in lista_aziende_raw if x in parsing_name] 

print(lista_aziende_filtered)
```

I also tried to put it in an `if statement`, following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70327379/filtering-a-list-of-strings) but that spits out `TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable'`.

```
lista_aziende_raw = []
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    lista_aziende_raw.append(link.get('href')) 

print(lista_aziende_raw)

def parser(starting_list):
    parsing_name = 'Azienda'
    lista_aziende_filtered = []

    for x in starting_list:
        if parsing_name in x:
            lista_aziende_filtered.append(x)
    return lista_aziende_filtered

print(parser(lista_aziende_raw))
```

What am I missing? How would you do it?

EDIT: [Here](https://pastebin.com/Expbauqt) the output of `print(lista_aziende_raw)`.
The full error for the list comprehension:

```
File "/home/enrico/Documents/Learning_Python/edo/web_scraper.py", line 41, in <listcomp>
    lista_aziende_filtered = [x for x in lista_aziende_raw if x in parsing_name] 
                                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not NoneType
```

Full error for the `if` statement:

```
 print(parser(lista_aziende_raw))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/enrico/Documents/Learning_Python/edo/web_scraper.py", line 27, in parser
    if parsing_name in x:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

Comment: `parsing_name` is a list so not really.

Comment: I see now. Bit odd to do it that way though.

Comment: After flipping `parsing_name` and `x`, and setting `parsing_name = 'Azienda'`, it gives me the same `Typerror` as in the `if` statement

Comment: Your second attempt should work, can you paste what `print(lista_aziende_raw)` returns? And add a bit more context on what TypeError you get, on which line of code.

Comment: Just edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the elements you're parsing is returning a None (`lista_aziende_raw[10]`) Modify your initial block to:

```py
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    link_text = link.get('href')
    if isinstance(link_text, str): # check that the link_text is a string
        lista_aziende_raw.append(link_text)
```

What the additional `isinstance(link_text, str)` does is to check that the object returned by `link.get` is a string. You could also directly do `if link_str:...` since `None` evaluates to `False`, though I used the more explicit check for clarity.

And your second attempt as well as the other suggestion should work.

The only other problem is that most of your urls actually have 'azienda' in lowercase, so you should do `if "azienda" in x.lower()` for your condition.

Comment: Tell me if I understand correctly you addition. You use that `isinstance` to get rid of the `None` element, so that only iterable results are appended, right?

Comment: @enrico223 to be precise, I am checking that link_text is a string, so we only append things which are strings. I have added some additional clarification in my answer.